# How to build full Core-Plot with iphone project?

Tags: iphone, graph, charts, core-plot

Currently I completed my project using with CorePlot. But I have
problem, when I copy my project to another folder, prepare to build
before distribution, I have one problem:
      CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory

I did my project import Core-Plot like the way with this link:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone...

I knew that my project just reference to Core-Plot library, so when I
copy my project to another folder. The reference is broken. Can anyone
tell me how can I import CorePlot with my project, so that I can copy
my project and run anywhere?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the reference type (drop-down-list that appears when you try to link to the .h file - or any other file) to "Absolute path".

**EDIT**:
Notice that this way if you will copy the project to another computer then you will have problem again.

I have one "Projects" folder where all my projects are stored and all the external libraries that I might use in several projects are located in one "External Libraries" folder. This way I never have this problem...
I use "Default" reference type, which is relative and not absolute...